# Solving a system with 4 variables and 4 equations

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve a linear system of equations with Mathematica. 
My variables are `x1, x2, x3, x4`. I use the code shown below, but it gives error saying that:

> Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.

Even when I used `LinearSolve`, I got the same error.

```
Solve[{(x1 - ((-m3* n2 + m2 * z3 - 0.5*m2*z3)* x2 + (0.5 *n2* z3)*
       x3 + (0.5 *m2 * z3)*x4)/((-1.5) n2* z3)) == (2/
     1.5)   ,  (x2 -  ((m3* n2 - 0.5*m3 *n2 - m2 * z3)*
       x1 + (0.5* m3* n2)* x3 + (0.5* m2* m3)* 
       x4)/((-1.5) (m2* m3)) ) == (-m3* n2 + m2* z3 )/((-1.5) m2* 
      m3)  ,    (x3 - ((-n2*  z1 + .5*n2 * z1)*
       x1 + (.5* m2 * z1 - m2 * z1)*x2 + (m1 *n2  - 0.5* m2* z1)*
       x4 )/((1.5) n2 z1) ) ==  (2/1.5 )  ,   ( 
    x4 - ((-m1 *n2 + 0.5*m1 *n2 )*x1 + (-0.5 *m1* m2) *
       x2 + (-.5* m1* n2 + m2 *z1)*x3)/((1.5) m1* m2) ) == ( 
     m1* n2 - m2* z1)/((1.5)* m1* m2)} , {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

Can anyone help me please. I really appreciate your comments.

Comment: Apparently, your equations have a certain redundancy such that there is a 1-paremeterfamily of solutions (parameterized by `x1`).

Comment: You can select which of your variables is the parameter: `FullSimplify[
 Solve[eqns//Rationalize, #, Reals] & /@ Subsets[{x1, x2, x3, x4}, {3}]]`

Comment: Use Reduce instead of Solve.

Comment: In this case, you probably want to use `1/2` rather than `0.5`. This uses exact numbers rather than approximate numbers.

Comment: @BobHanlon , I still get the same problem.

Comment: Any other idea?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher , can you please explain more? Still I have a problem with solving this system.

Answer (score 2):

*Extended comment.*

```
eq = Rationalize@{(x1 - ((-m3*n2 + m2*z3 - 0.5*m2*z3)*x2 + (0.5*n2*z3)*
          x3 + (0.5*m2*z3)*x4)/((-1.5) n2*z3)) == (2/
      1.5), (x2 - ((m3*n2 - 0.5*m3*n2 - m2*z3)*x1 + (0.5*m3*n2)*
          x3 + (0.5*m2*m3)*x4)/((-1.5) (m2*m3))) == (-m3*n2 + 
       m2*z3)/((-1.5) m2*
       m3), (x3 - ((-n2*z1 + .5*n2*z1)*x1 + (.5*m2*z1 - m2*z1)*
          x2 + (m1*n2 - 0.5*m2*z1)*x4)/((1.5) n2 z1)) == (2/
      1.5), (x4 - ((-m1*n2 + 0.5*m1*n2)*x1 + (-0.5*m1*m2)*
          x2 + (-.5*m1*n2 + m2*z1)*x3)/((1.5) m1*m2)) == (m1*n2 - 
       m2*z1)/((1.5)*m1*m2)};
sol = Solve[eq, {x1, x2, x3, x4}][[1]];
```

The generic solution looks like this:

```
{x1, x2, x3, x4} /. sol
```

> {x1, -(z3/m3) + (x1 z3)/   m3, -((m1 x1 (m3 n2 + m2 z3))/(m3 (m1 n2 +
>   m2 z1))) - (-2 m1 m3 n2 -
>       m2 m3 z1 - m1 m2 z3)/(m3 (m1 n2 + m2 z1)), (z1 (m3 n2 + m2 z3))/(   m3 (m1 n2 + m2 z1)) - (x1 z1 (m3 n2 + m2 z3))/(m3 (m1 n2 + m2 z1))}

Let's check that these really are solutions by substituting the solutions rules `sol` into the equation `eq`:

```
eq /. sol // Simplify
```

> {True, True, True, True}

So the equations do not specify a single solution. Because there are 4 equations and four variables, that means that the equations are somewhat redundant. Usually, one would expect to get only finitely many (or countably many) solution. This is not the case here: We have a continuum of solutions. Because that is somewhat unexpected (and because this often causes problems), `Solve` warns us. That's all. The message is a warning, not an error.

Comment: I got it. Your explanation was great.

Comment: If you like, you can mark it as "accepted", signaling that your question is answered.